# Turns Ratio and Transformation Ratio

Tags: transformer

I am not able to understand the difference between this two terms. I searched it online but did not get an appropriate answer anywhere.

Comment: *Transformation Ratio* is not commonly used and, when it is, it produces misunderstanding (as seen here and below). Stick with turns ratio (primary to secondary) or step-up ratio (secondary to primary). These are pretty unambiguous amongst EEs.

Comment: But transformation ratios are used while referring from from one side of transformer to another.

Comment: But - it's not commonly used etc...

Comment: The accepted standard (in the U.S. at least) would be IEEE Std C57. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEE Std C57.12.80 defines the "Standard Terminology for Power and Distribution Transformers".

IEEE Std C57.12.80-2010 defines the "turn ratio of a transformer" (not turn**s** ratio) as the ratio of turns in a higher voltage winding to the turns in a lower voltage winding. The definition says nothing about "primary" or "secondary".

The IEEE standard does not define a "transformation ratio".

However, the standard also says that the "turn ratio of a current transformer" is defined as the ratio of secondary to primary turns, while the "turn ratio of a voltage transformer" is defined as the ratio of primary to secondary turns.

For what it's worth, I have two textbooks on my shelf that define the "turns ratio" as the number of secondary turns divided by the number of primary turns.

Answer (score 1):

Transformation Ratio:
http://www.electrical-engineering-assignment.com/voltage-transformation-ratio-k

> The transformation ratio is defined as the ratio of the secondary voltage to primary voltage.

And Turns Ratio would be the number turns of the primary winding to the secondary winding (edit: those were swapped originally).  Some transformers have multiple secondary windings as well to create multiple outputs.
More if there are more secondary turns than primary turns, the secondary voltage will be higher than primary voltage, and if fewer, the secondary voltage will be lower than primary voltage.

Comment: But we define a=Turns in Primary/Turns in Secondary as I have seen usually. I think it is also defined as the ratio of turns in high voltage side to turns in low voltage side.

Comment: The two are related. Say you had a transformer with 100 turns primary, 10 turns secondary. Input voltage of 120VAC, 0.1A -> output voltage would 12VAC, 1A (with appropriate load).  Transfomation ratio is then 12/120 = 0.1, while turns ratio = 10/100 = 0.1.  Unless it is flipped as you said, then 100/10 = 10.

Comment: Your definition of turns ratio is incorrect. Since now, according to IEEE definition, the turns ratio of a transformer is the ratio of the number of turns in a higher voltage winding to that in a lower voltage winding.

Comment: Oh, so now you Do have an appropriate answer?  Then update your question with that so only the missing part is addressed.

Comment: I wanted to know the difference between them and you gave me a good answer. Only your definitiom of turns ratio was incorrect. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: swapped the primary/secondary in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, some definitions:

- Turns ratio is a ratio of number of turns on primary side \$N_p\$ to the number of turns on secondary side \$N_s\$:

$$\upsilon_N = \frac{N_p}{N_s}$$

- Transformation (voltage) ratio is a ratio of primary voltage \$V_p\$ to the secondary voltage \$V_s\$, both measured in idle state (without a load on secondary side):

$$\upsilon_V = \frac{V_p}{V_s}$$

In almost all cases You can assume that voltage ratio is equal to turns ratio, \$\upsilon_V \approx \upsilon_N\$, but in reality they not. Look at the transformer equivalent circuit:

[image]

Real transformer have some resistances of windings \$R_p\$ and \$R_s\$ (here secondary side reactance and resistance are transformed on primary side), core losses (represented as \$R_C\$) and magnetizing reactance \$X_M\$. Depending on the load (current in the windings) these elements cause voltage drops so ratio of voltages measured on both windings will not be the same as \$\upsilon_V\$.

Comment: @JohnCena Just accept/upvote the answer.

Comment: Just last thing. Just tell me that if turns ratio and transformation ratio is equal in non- ideal transformer also.

Comment: @JohnCena All my answer is about a non-ideal transformer. In ideal there are any resistances, core losses or magnetizing current, so voltage ratio equals turns ratio. But ideal transformers doesn't exist (except those in SPICE software).